# Laravel Gate for authorization check

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization, laravel-5.3

I used Gate for laravel authorization where **A user have One role and one role have Multiple Permissions.** I used the following method for checking role has permission or not. But it doesn't work properly means user may have chance to access one route though I have given him multiple permissions through roles.
See the scenario is suppose admin can see list of users as well can access test route. But in my case admin can see list of users but he can't access the test route. Though I have given him the access in permission table.

Can anyone suggest what's the problem here?

```
 public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {

        $gate->define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->role->id === $permission->role_id;
        });
    }
}

public function getPermissions()
{
    return Permission::with('role')->get();
}
```

In controller Code :

```
public function test(){

    if(Gate::allows('test')){
        echo "This is Test";
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your code where the above doesn't work (and if possible where it does work)?

Comment: I have updated the Question, please check it once.

Comment: sorry check now